# Mapstruct unmappedTargetPolicy WARN seems to have no effect

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, mapstruct

I am using Mapstruct 1.3.0 to project this source object;

```
import lombok.Data;
@Data
public class SimpleSource {
    private String firstField;
    private String secondField;
    private String noMappingDefined;
}
```

Into this DTO:

```
import lombok.Data;
@Data
public class SimpleDestination {

    private String field1;
    private String field2;

}
```

In my interface I have not defined any mapping for the field "noMappingDefined"

```
@Mapper
public interface TestMapper {
    @Mapping(source = "firstField", target = "field1")
    @Mapping(source = "secondField", target = "field2")
    SimpleDestination sourceToDestination(SimpleSource source);

    @InheritInverseConfiguration
    SimpleSource destinationToSource(SimpleDestination destination);

}
```

Setting the unmappedTargetPolicy to WARN in the compilerArgs in the POM does not result in any notifications when I build the project and the field with no mapping is nowhere to be seen in the target class generated by Mapstruct.

```
        <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
            <annotationProcessorPaths>
                <path>
                    <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                    <version>1.3.0.Beta2</version>
                </path>
                <path>
                    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                </path>                 
            </annotationProcessorPaths>
            <compilerArgs>
                <compilerArg>
                    -Amapstruct.defaultComponentModel=spring                        
                </compilerArg>
                <compilerArg>
                    -Amapstruct.unmappedTargetPolicy=WARN
                </compilerArg>
            </compilerArgs>
        </configuration>
```

The generated class does not include the unmapped field as expected but I had hoped to see a warning when I built the project.

If I change the unmappedTargetPolicy to ERROR then the build fails.

The behaviour is the same whether I configure this in the POM or in the @Mapper annotation on the interface.

Has anyone else run into this issue? I'm working on a project which has hundreds of fields to map, not all of them are critical but it would be nice to know if I've missed any.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a POM issue, I added the showWarnings tag and set it to true;

```
            <showWarnings>
                true
            </showWarnings>
            <compilerArgs>
                <compilerArg>
                    -Amapstruct.defaultComponentModel=spring                        
                </compilerArg>
                <compilerArg>
                    -Amapstruct.unmappedTargetPolicy=WARN
                </compilerArg>
            </compilerArgs>
```

And now I'm seeing the warnings I expected when I build the project.